# Different deploy preview environments for different branches in Netlify

Tags: netlify

I have a repository deployed with Netlify. We deploy a `staging` branch and a `production` branch.

.toml looks like this

```
[context.production.environment]
  APP_ENV = "production"

[context.staging.environment]
  APP_ENV = "staging"

[context.deploy-preview.environment]
  APP_ENV = "staging"
```

The problem is that when we make a pull request to production, we get the staging environment and not the production one.

How can we create different environments for deploy-previews based on branches?